# Formatting training dataset for SpaCy NER

Tags: json, format, training-data, named-entity-recognition, spacy

I want to train a blank model for NER with my own entities. To do this, I need to use a dataset, which is currently in .csv form and features entity tags in the following format (I'll provide one example row for each relevant column):

---

Column: sentence

Value:  I want apples

---

Column: data

Value:  ['want;@command;2;6','apples';@fruit;7;13']

---

Column: entity

Value:  I @command @fruit

---

Column: entity_types

Value: @bot/@command;@bot/@food/@fruit

---

In order to train SpaCy's NER, I need the training data as json in the following form:

```
    TRAIN_DATA = [
    ('Who is Shaka Khan?', {
        'entities': [(7, 17, 'PERSON')]
    }),
    ('I like London and Berlin.', {
        'entities': [(7, 13, 'LOC'), (18, 24, 'LOC')]
    })
]
```

[Link to the relevant part in the SpaCy Docs](https://spacy.io/usage/training#ner)

I've tried to find a solution for how I could re-format the data from the csv to the format required by SpaCy, but I was unsuccessful as of yet. The dataset does contain all the necessary information - text string, entity names, entity types, entity offsets - but I simply don't know how to get them in the correct form.

I would appreciate any and all help concerning how I would accomplish this!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It wasn't 100% clear from your question whether you're also asking about the CSV extraction – so I'll just assume this is not the problem. (If it is, this should be pretty easy to achieve using the `csv` module. If the CSV data is messy and contains a bunch of stuff combined in one string, you might have to call `split` on it and do it the hacky way.)

If you're able to extract the "sentence" and "data" column in a format like this, you're actually very close to spaCy's training format already:

```
[{ 
    'sentence': 'I want apples'
    'data': [('want', '@command', 2, 6) ('apples', '@fruit', 7, 13)]
}]
```

It seems like your data counts the end character differently and with an offset of `+1` compared to spaCy. So you'll have to adjust this by subtracting `1`. I'm probably making this a lot more verbose than it should be, but I hope this makes it easier to follow:

```
TRAIN_DATA = []

for example in your_extracted_data:  # see example above
    entities = []
    for entity in example['data']:  # iterate over the entities
        text, label, start, end = entity  # ('want', '@command', 2, 6)
        label = label.split('@')[1].upper()  # not necessary, but nicer
        end = end - 1  # correct the end character index
        entities.append((start, end, label))
    # add training example of (text, annotations) tuple
    TRAIN_DATA.append((example['sentence'], {'entities': entities}))
```

This should give you training data that looks like this:

```
[
    ('I want apples', {'entities': [(2, 5, 'COMMAND'), (7, 12, 'FRUIT')]})
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer really is helping me out and is exactly what I was trying to figure out!

I can see how the code would work on the extracted data, but I am still missing a step in the CSV extraction process and I would appreciate it if you or anyone else reading this could point me in the right direction:

As you said, the CSV did contain a bunch of stuff in one string, but I managed to hack everything apart, leaving me with a pandas df containing a `sentence` column and 10 `data` columns (because some sentences include up to 10 different entities.

Comment: A `data` cell therefore contains either something like `'want', '@command', 2, 6` or `NaN`.

What I'm still unclear about is how I turn this pandas dataframe into that format you gave as an example. Or, more specifically, what this format is and which terms I should google to learn about how to turn the df into it.

Am I right in assuming that it consists of tuples nested inside lists nested inside a dictionary?

Comment: Yes – the desired format is a list of tuples, containing a string (the text) and a dictionary. The dictionary has one entry `'entities'`, and its value is a list of tuples (triples) consisting of two integers (the start and end index) and a string (the label). I'm not that familiar with pandas dataframe, but it definitely seems like a common use case – so I'm sure you'll be able to figure this out. Even if you can only extract long strings – as long as their format is consistent, you can always write a hacky converter script in Python using `split`, `strip` etc.